# Error with simple cloud function to copy a document

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating my first cloud function that simply copies a document in subcollection `journal` into subcollection `activites` after it's created. I'd like the copied document to have the same `postId`. The Function Log shows

```
Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.
at Object.validateResourcePath (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/path.js:406:15)
at CollectionReference.doc (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1982:20)
at exports.onCreateJournal.functions.firestore.document.onCreate (/workspace/index.js:21:8)
at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23)
at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:198:28)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:6
```

Here's the cloud function

```
exports.onCreateJournal = functions.firestore
  .document("/users/{userId}/journal/{docID}")
  .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    const data = snapshot.data();
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const postId = context.params.postId;

    admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("activities")
      .doc(postId)
      .set(data);
  });
```

Or should I be debugging this with the Firestore emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message:

> Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.

is suggesting that you passed an empty string or some other invalid value (such as undefined) to one of your calls to `doc()`.  My guess is it's the second one.

Your wildcard path has "docID" in it, but you are trying to access it with a different name "postId".  You will need to use the same name for both.  Perhaps you meant to use a wildcard like this:

```
exports.onCreateJournal = functions.firestore
  .document("/users/{userId}/journal/{postId}")
```

Notice that I replaced "docID" with "postId" to match your code.

Comment: Ah. Thanks Doug! I didn't realize the string was parsed for params. Very cool.